# Is it possible to render an equirectangular image in Blender Internal?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, camera

Hear me out. I know there's a "panoramic" mode for cameras now. Thing is, it only works with Cycles. Cycles does not support some things, like particles (halo, line). I need particles, I also need to render an equirectangular render of the scene.

What can I do? Even some mulitple camera setup + external tool would work. Note that I need animations though, an image editor won't do.

Comment: Cycles supports *particles*, it just doesn't have equivalents to BI *particle materials*. You could try instancing objects to the particles, then dress them up in the compositor to get the look you want (e.g. glowy halos, motion blur).

Comment: Nothing on instanced 3d meshes can easily mimic halo or line particles. Try recreating complex fireworks in Cycles from 3d mesh particles... yeah...

Comment: Some kind of camera setup + external tool would do, again.

Comment: Not dublicate. Although I will need to edit the topic title. I need particles to work too. The answer there is a good solution and is worth to know, but doesn't support particles/hairs as those aren't mirrored which some users will need.

Comment: It seems to me you have two different questions: one on equirectangular porjections (that seems to have an answer) and one on particles. To keep things in order on the site please ask the second one on  a different post.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't have an answer, because the solution doesn't work for scenes with non-solid objects (like particles) because they are not mirrored. It is a 100% solution for limited cases.